# Comparing websockets with long-polling

Tags: php, websocket, benchmarking, comet, long-polling

I would like to measure and compare server-performance between long-polling and websockets. I have built a simple PHP-application with ratchet(php websockets) that just outputs data in the console(guide: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world). The long-polling app is also PHP and just generating random numbers and logging them in the console(this post: [How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)).

Is there any way to do a fair comparison between these applications without using a database? which tool(s) should I use to measure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommand Zabbix.

It gives you alot of information about the server overload.

You can also try xDebug.